# $\operatorname{Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(R/(a))) =\operatorname{Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(R))-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, transcendence-degree

Let $R$ be a commuative (noetherian?) integral domain and $Q=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$.
Assume that $\operatorname{Trdeg}(Q) := n < \infty$. Let $a \in R$
a nonzero prime element of $R$. I want to understand if that's true that
$\operatorname{Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(R/(a)))= n-1$ without
using PID and identification of Krull dimension of the ring
with transcendence degree of accociated field of fractions. Is there
a direct argument known with similar spirit as for
$R= K[x_1,...,x_n]$ that quoting out a nonzero prime element of $R$
reduces the maximal number of algebraically independent elements
of $\operatorname{Frac}(R/(a))$?

In case of $R= K[x_1,...,x_n]$ we deal with special case where
the transcendental basis $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$
already generate the ring, so quoting every nonzero $f \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$
provides already a nontrivial algebraic relation between
$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and
$\operatorname{Trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(K[x_1,...,x_n]/(f)))
=\operatorname{Trdeg}(K(x_1,...,x_n))-1$ is automatically satisfied
for prime $f$. Can this argument can be adapted for arbitrary commuative noetherian domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean an integral domain? The transcendence degree over the prime field? $(a)$ not containing any non-zero integer (ie. not $a=2,R=\Bbb{Z}$) ? If so then $$Tr\deg(Frac(R/(a)))\le Tr\deg(Frac(R))-1$$ use that $R$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Z}/(c)[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $c$ is the characteristic and $x_1=a$.

Then try with $R=\bigcup_{k\ge 1}\Bbb{Q}[x_1,x_2/x_1^k],a=x_1$ to see that sometimes $$Tr\deg(Frac(R/(a)))=Tr\deg(Frac(R))-2$$
But this ring is not Noetherian as $I_k=(x_2/x_1^k)$ is a strictly increasing sequence of ideals.

Comment: Yes I mean an integral domain. I think that also in spirit of
your hint we can work with $R= k[x_1,..., x_n]/P$ where 
$k= \mathbb{Z}/(c)$ and $P$ prime ideal of $k[x_1,..., x_n]$.
So the question stays why if we take a nonzero $a \in R$ then
the transcendence degree of $R/(a)$ drops by $1$ from that one of $R$?

Comment: For $R= k[x_1,..., x_n]$ that's easy but for arbitrary $P$ I don't know how to solve it without identification of trdeg with Krull dimension. Indeed, applying this identification it's easy to show to claim, but I'm curious if one can show it without this tool

Comment: Because $x_1=a$. That's a general property of transcendence bases: we can take for $x_1$ any non-algebraic element, and the cardinality of the base won't depend on this choice.

Comment: I'm not getting on with the calculation in your example 
$R=\bigcup_{k\ge 1}\Bbb{Q}[x_1,x_2/x_1^k]$ and $R/(a)$ with
$a:=x_1$. The case $Tr\deg(Frac(R))$ looks not hard. For every
$k \ge 1$ we have $\Bbb{Q}[x_1,x_2] \subset \Bbb{Q}[x_1,x_2/x_1^k]$
and $\Bbb{Q}[x_1,x_2/x_1^k] \subset \Bbb{Q}(x_1,x_2)$, so
$Frac(R)= \Bbb{Q}(x_1,x_2)$ as I see so far, is this calculation
correct? Then trgeg is $2$.

Comment: If yes we come to 
$Frac(R/(a))$ now. It contains a gap I can't solve: For every
$k \ge 1$ we can in $Frac(R/(a))$ invert $x_2/x_1^k$ but 
$(x_2/x_1^k)/(x_2/x_1^{k+1})= x_1 $ gives zero as we killed it
by construction. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $R/(a) = \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: oh yes i see, in $R$ we have the relation $x_2/x_1^k= x_1 \cdot x_2/x_1^{k+1}$
and this kills in $R/x_1$ every $x_2/x_1^k$ as well, 
so $R/(a) = \Bbb{Q}$ as you said, thank you!